# What does sed 's/^*//g' do?

Tags: sed

I don't understand what the following command does in Unix:

```bash
sed 's/^*//g'
```

I tried searching for it in Google, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatives to *Google* are `info` and `man` which will give you the documentation of *your* implementation and version of `sed` rather than some random one on the internet. On a GNU system, try `info -n 'the "s" command' sed` for instance here. If you're not familiar with `info`, you can start with `info info` (`man man` for `man`)

Comment: Are you asking what the `sed` command does _in general_, or are you asking what it does with _these specific arguments_?

Comment: "I tried searching for it in Google, but no luck." When I put `sed` into Google by itself, the third result I get is a [detailed tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). Did you try to follow through that? Are you expecting that `sed foo` can be *directly* explained, *for every possible `foo`*? If so, **why**? Would you take the same approach to learning, for example, a programming language? Because `sed` basically is one.

Comment: Separately: did you try to use it? If not, why not - how did you come up with the command, and why is it a concern for you? (Is someone else on the Internet trying to get you to use it, for example?) If so - what appeared to happen when you tried it? Why does this not answer the question - what more specifically do you want to know?

Comment: Also, try https://explainshell.com/

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have a colleague who googles "man <cmd>" instead of using his terminal.  He tried to google "man man" and regretted it.

Answer (score 36):

The given `sed` command attempts to remove a single `*` character from the start of every line of input.

The `sed` utility is generally used for line-by-line text modifications on files or data streams.  The command in the question edits its standard input stream since no filename operand is given on the command line.  It applies the editing expression `s/^*//g` to each line of input, which is a substitution command that removes whatever matches the regular expression `^*` (or rather, it substitutes it with nothing, which has the same effect).

The initial `^` in the expression is an "anchor" that forces the expression to match at the start of a line. The `*` character is usually "special" in regular expressions (it allows the previous expression to match zero or more times, as in `ab*`, which will match `a`, `ab`, `abb` etc.)  However, when `*` is the first character (possibly after an initial `^` anchor), it matches the literal character `*`.

This holds true for POSIX *basic* regular expressions, which is what `sed` (and `grep`) uses by default.  Your `sed` may also support POSIX *extended* regular expressions, where putting `*` first (or immediately after `^`) is *undefined* and may result in an error:

```bash
$ sed -E 's/^*//g'
sed: 1: "s/^*//g": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

The `g` at the end is not having any effect.  This flag means "repeat the substitution for every non-overlapping match on the line", but since the expression is anchored to the start of the line with `^`, there will be, at most, a single such match.

Example:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'a*a' 'bb*' '***' '*abc'
a*a
bb*
***
*abc
```

Our `sed` expression is expected to remove a single `*` from the start of the two last lines above.

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'a*a' 'bb*' '***' '*abc' | sed 's/^*//'
a*a
bb*
**
abc
```

Just showing that adding the `g` at the end makes no difference:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'a*a' 'bb*' '***' '*abc' | sed 's/^*//g'
a*a
bb*
**
abc
```

It's not until we remove the anchoring that the `g` flag has an effect:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'a*a' 'bb*' '***' '*abc' | sed 's/*//g'
aa
bb

abc
```

This particular modification would be more efficiently performed by

```bash
tr -d '*'
```

---

Since `*` matches a literal `*` character when it occurs first in a basic regular expression, the expression `*$`, which uses the end-of-line anchor `$`, would match a single `*` at the end of a line.  The following, therefore, shows how to remove a `*` character at the end of a line:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'a*a' 'bb*' '***' '*abc' | sed 's/*$//'
a*a
bb
**
*abc
```

As you can see, this affects the second and third lines of our example data.

Comment: `echo "*abc*def"|sed -E 's/^[*]//g' => abc*def` works (sed 4.8), but [regex101](https://regex101.com/) accepts but does not match. I can't see why.

Comment: @Jim Note that the site you refer to does not support POSIX regular expressions. It defaults to Perl-compatible regular expressions and allows you to use other types of regular expressions too, all of which (I think) could be seen as _extensions_ to the POSIX _extended_ regular expression syntax. The PCRE `^[*]` would match a literal `*` at the start of the line (which I believe the site actually shows). And again, the `g` at the end does not have any effect whatsoever since you are anchoring the expression with `^`.